# How to pass SOAP header with key in karate

Tags: soap, header, karate

I want to call below request with Karate:

```
http://testsample.com/test?request=<REQUESTS>
<REQUEST TYPE="createClientAccount" REF_NUM="A1">
<CRM_ID>ABC_123</CRM_ID>
<CRM_SYSTEM_ID>abc</CRM_SYSTEM_ID>       
<AUTO_APPROVE>TRUE</AUTO_APPROVE>
</REQUEST>
</REQUESTS>
```

I have tried below option but it did not work, Can someone please suggest whats wrong here?

```
Given url 'http://testsample.com/test'
And request
"""
<REQUESTS>
<REQUEST TYPE="createClientAccount" REF_NUM="A1">
<CRM_ID>ABC_123</CRM_ID>
<CRM_SYSTEM_ID>abc</CRM_SYSTEM_ID>       
<AUTO_APPROVE>TRUE</AUTO_APPROVE>
</REQUEST>
</REQUESTS>
"""
And header Content-Type = 'application/soap+xml'
When method post
Then status 200
```

Comment: when I try to directly call the XML in URL like I am doing in postman I get this error: 
 'Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuck, that looks like a terribly designed API. Are you sure you are trying to send that XML as part of the URL ? Then do this:

```
* string xml = <REQUESTS><REQUEST TYPE="createClientAccount" REF_NUM="A1"><CRM_ID>ABC_123</CRM_ID><CRM_SYSTEM_ID>abc</CRM_SYSTEM_ID><AUTO_APPROVE>TRUE</AUTO_APPROVE></REQUEST></REQUESTS> 
Given url 'http://testsample.com/test'
And param request = xml
And request ''
When method post
```

If you are new to HTTP and REST please take the help of someone.

Comment: Many thanks Peter..that worked. :)  but I also want to parameterize CRM ID in the XML which comes from the response of earlier call. but when I do it like below it comments out content after #.            `* string xml = <REQUESTS><REQUEST TYPE="createClientAccount" REF_NUM="A1"><CRM_ID>#(CRMID)</CRM_ID>`

Comment: looks like you are new to stack-overflow. can you please "accept" this answer. and since we have to use a `string` above, embedded expressions won't work. please search the doc for `replace`. and ask another question if needed.